# Passing value from dropdown bootstrap to next php page

Tags: php, html, css, dropdown

How do i pass a value on dropdown bootstrap to the next page. There several options to choose and obviously it would be a waste of time making multiple same layout page but with different contents. How do i pass the value from dropdown to the next php page so that the next page can load the data based on that value.
I've seen some examples using the form method but it ruins the dropdown layout.Using bootstrap 3.3.7. Thanks in advance

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="regdonee.php">Register Donee</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>    
  <li class=""><a href="homepage.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">State <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="johor.php">Johor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Selangor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Melaka</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Penang</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Perak</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pahang</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kedah</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kelantan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Terengganu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Negeri Sembilan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Perlis</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sabah</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sarawak</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You can pass the data to next page by changing anchor tags to something like this <li><a href="page-url?id=selangor">Selangor</a></li>

Answer (score 1):

href should be something like

```
<li><a href="page.php?sel=Johor">Johor</a></li>
<li><a href="page.php?sel=Selangor">Selangor</a></li>
<li><a href="page.php?sel=Melaka">Melaka</a></li>
```

in page.php use `$_GET['sel']` to get the selected value